# Form action gives object not found error in wordpress template

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a PHP file(validate.php) placed in a theme folder, and login form template word press. I got the error: "Object Not Found Error".

**The following code is what I wrote:**

```
<form action="validate.php" method="post">
 and also tried with  
<form name="userlogin" method="post" action="<?php echo network_site_url(); ?>/validate.php">
```

Please give the solution as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a WordPress URL not a link to a php file.

Be sure to understand the anatomy of a WordPress theme:
http://yoast.com/wordpress-theme-anatomy/

Comment: just i created the one file name called as validate.php and placed in the respective word press theme folder. when i trying to call the file with following code <form action="validate.php"....> it raising the error as object not found, can u please help me out of this problem